# How to have type hinting in PHP that specifies variable scope inside of a template? (specifically PhpStorm)

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm looking for a doc comment that would define the scope/context of the current php template. (similar to @var)

Example View Class:

```
<?php

class ExampleView {

    protected $pageTitle;

    public function __construct($title) {
        $this->pageTitle = $title;
    }

    public function render() {
        require_once 'template.php';
    }

}
```

--

```
<?php
// template.php 

/** @var $this ExampleView */
echo $this->pageTitle;
```

PHPStorm gives an inspection error because the access on $pageTitle is protected.

[image]

Is there a hint to give scope?  Something like:

```
<?php
// template.php 
/** @scope ExampleView */ // <---????

/** @var $this ExampleView */
echo $this->pageTitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot -- there is no such tag (either in general or specific to PhpStorm).

Let's hope they (JetBrains devs) do something about it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11022 -- vote/comment/etc and if it will get much more votes we may see it implemented soon (right now that "soon" is far away).